# Enable Zoom on an ESNet react-timeseries-charts Chart

Tags: reactjs, charts, time-series, timeserieschart

I'm currently playing with [ESnet's react timeseries charting components](http://software.es.net/react-timeseries-charts/#/), with the specific goal of allowing a user to zoom into a displayed chart, as in their [currency example](http://software.es.net/react-timeseries-charts/#/example/currency).

According to [their documentation](http://software.es.net/react-timeseries-charts/#/api/charts/ChartContainer) and to the best of my understanding of the example's source code, it should be enough, if one is rendering a chart like this:

```
<ChartContainer timeRange={series.range()}>
   ...
</ChartContainer>
```

To add `enablePanZoom={true}` to the props to enable zooming. E.g:

```
<ChartContainer timeRange={series.range()} enablePanZoom={true}>
   ...
</ChartContainer>
```

However, this is not working and I cannot understand why. I guess something from the doc or the example eludes me:

- running the zoomable examples locally works as expected
- running the non-zoomable example with the zoom flag enabled does not work

Hence, the question: **How to make a react-timeseries-charts chart zoomable?**

**edit**: Turns out the answer was obvious: one *must* make use of `onTimeRangeChanged` and update the state, otherwise, well, poof...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On their example, they use 
`onTimeRangeChanged={this.handleTimeRangeChange}`

if you look in the example source code, at https://github.com/esnet/react-timeseries-charts/blob/master/src/website/packages/charts/examples/currency/Index.js

they define the function as

```
handleTimeRangeChange = timerange => {
    this.setState({ timerange });
};
```

Have you tried that?

Comment: Indeed, the range must be tracked in the state and updated via that callback. The documentation left me feeling that this was not necessary :(